# I'm writing a c++ mandelbrot generator but I need to work with HSV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm starting with a black `cv::Mat` image but I would like to add HSV to it. How do I achieve this??

```
int RE_START = -2;
int RE_END = 1;
int IM_START = -1;
int IM_END = 1;

int MAX_ITER = 80;

int mandelbrot(std::complex<double> c){
    std::complex<double> z{0,0};
    int n = 0;
    while (abs(z) <= 2 && n < MAX_ITER){
        z = z*z + c;
        n += 1;
    }   
    return n;
}
int m;
int main()
{
    //! [mandelbrot-transformation]
    Mat mandelbrotImg(width, height,CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    Mat mandelHSV(width, height,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    float wid = (float)width;
    float hei = (float)height;
    int count = 0;
    for (int x=0; x < width; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<height; y++){
            
            std::complex<double> c( RE_START + (x / wid) * (RE_END - RE_START),
                    IM_START + (y / hei) * (IM_END - IM_START));

            m = mandelbrot(c);
            
            double hue = (255 * m / (float)MAX_ITER);
            double saturation = 255.0;
            double value;
            if (m < MAX_ITER) {
                value = 255;
            }else {
               value = 0;
            }
            mandelbrotImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y) = ((uchar)hue, (uchar)saturation, (uchar)value);
            
            count++;
            
        }
    }
    cv::cvtColor(mandelbrotImg, mandelbrotImg, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    imwrite("../img/mandle.png", mandelbrotImg);
    
    }
    
};
```

This is what I have so far!
I dont know if I need to convert it or assign the HSV value at the pixel location.

- I've added floating point division
- I've added norm(z) into mandelbrot

The image output is now:

[image: IMAGE OUTPUT]

Expected output:

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

Comment: You need to convert to rgb just before saving, using `cvtColor` with `CV_HSV2RGB`.

Comment: Ok, I'll use cv::cvtColor(mandelbrotImg, mandelHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
but in my code the mandelbrot() function outputs the same value but I'm not sure why?

Comment: You actually need the opposite conversion. You have h,s,v values in the cv::Mat but imwrite requires rgb (or rather bgr to be exact). So you need `COLOR_HSV2BGR`.

Comment: Ok, I've tried that but I'm just getting a black output :/

Comment: There's another issue with your calculation of `hue, saturation, value` from the result of `mandelbrot`. The only value I see is: 0,255,255.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same output of (3,255,255)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247786/discussion-between-bobaggins-and-wohlstad).

Comment: What are `width` and `height` (values and type)? If their type is integral `x/width` is an *integer* division.

Comment: Another issue: looks like `width`,`height` are integers, and therefore `(x / width)`,`(y / height)` are always 0 due to integer division. You need to cast in order to perform floating point division. Same appied to `m / MAX_ITER`.

Comment: @Bob__ width and height are integers.

Comment: OT: Consider `norm(z) <= 4`, to save a square root (see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/norm).

Comment: thanks I'm getting updated values now! but im still getting a black screen. @wohlstad

Comment: please see my changes above

Comment: Change `mandelHSV.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y) = (hue, saturation, value)` to `mandelbrotImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y) = cv::Vec3b( (uchar)hue, (uchar)saturation, (uchar)value );`. Your code is not assigning the pixel value as you expect (there is no such tupple in C++, it's just 3 values combined together with operator `,`).

Comment: I've made the changes @wohlstad the output is somewhat different. Please see image above

Comment: `z = std::norm(z) + c;` should be `z = z*z + c;`. `std::norm` returns the square of the norm, not the sqaure of the complex number.

Comment: Ok, changed it back again but the mandelbrot is rotated 90 degrees clockwise and doesn't have the colouring as I would expect - see the comparison picture. Thanks so much for your help btw @wohlstad

Comment: See my answer with all the fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were numerous issues in you original code, and there are still quite a few in your current one.

**To name some:**

1. `cv::Mat` constructor expects first the height, then the width.
2. `cv::Mat::at` method expects first the y coordinate, then the x.
3. The final color conversion should be `COLOR_HSV2BGR` **not** `COLOR_BGR2HSV`.
4. `mandelbrot` should better accept the parameter by `const&` to
   avoid copy (an efficiency issue).
5. Instead of checking `abs(z) <= 2`, it's better to use `norm(z) <= 4` since it avoids calculating the sqrt (an efficiency issue).
6. Since your main calculations are in `double`s, I swapped all the `float`s to `double`s.
7. There's no need to initialize the `cv::Mat` to a zero value upon construction, because later on we fill all the pixel values anyway.

**See fixed version:**

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <complex>


static const int RE_START = -2;
static const int RE_END = 1;
static const int IM_START = -1;
static const int IM_END = 1;
static const int MAX_ITER = 80;


int mandelbrot(std::complex<double> const & c) 
{
    std::complex<double> z{ 0,0 };
    int n = 0;
    while (std::norm(z) <= 4 && n < MAX_ITER) 
    {
        z = z*z + c;
        n += 1;
    }
    return n;
}


int main()
{
    int width = 960;
    int height = 640;

    cv::Mat mandelbrotImg(height, width, CV_8UC3);
    double wid = (double)width;
    double hei = (double)height;
    double reWidth = RE_END - RE_START;
    double imWidth = IM_END - IM_START;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
        {
            std::complex<double> c(RE_START + (x / wid) * reWidth, IM_START + (y / hei) * imWidth);
            int m = mandelbrot(c);

            double hue = (255 * m / (float)MAX_ITER);
            double saturation = 255.0;
            double value = (m < MAX_ITER) ? 255.0 : 0;

            mandelbrotImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = cv::Vec3b((uchar)hue, (uchar)saturation, (uchar)value);
        }
    }
    cv::cvtColor(mandelbrotImg, mandelbrotImg, cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR);
    cv::imwrite("../img/mandle.png", mandelbrotImg);
}
```

**Output:**
[image]